# Does Google Analytics tracking code tie to a specific domain?

Tags: google-analytics

A simple question.

When I set up Google Analytics and use the assigned tracking code, does GA automatically filter results coming from the Domain URL I specify for that tracking code?

In other words, if I used UA-1234567-8 on mysite.com and mysite2.com, will both sites get tracked or will just the site that's entered as my "Domain URL" in my account profile get tracked?  I can't seem to get definitive verification.

Comment: your question is better suited for webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8):

No. It's not tied to a definitive web property. The only affect setting the domain on the account has is for testing to see if the code is installed on the page (and that's just a nifty feature; you don't need to use it to get your data tracked).

No matter what the configured domain of the GA account is, it will execute and track.

If you cut and paste the stackoverflow.com GA code onto your site, your data would appear in their analytics report (assuming they didn't filter it out, like by hostname).